# CGPoints, NSValues, NSMutableArray and the ID Type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, core-graphics

I am trying to store CGPoints from UITouches in an Array. From reading other threads I have realized that using NSValue seems to be the best way to do this. 
Currently I have:

```
NSMutableArray *dotsArray;
NSValue *pointObj;
UITouch *touch = obj;
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
// Need to store the CGPoints, can't store directly into an array // as it is a C struct           // so we use NSValue
// CGPoint converted to NSValue
CGPoint point = touchPoint;
pointObj = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
dotsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pointObj,nil];
// Print to console the objects in the collection
NSLog(@"array content: %@", dotsArray);
NSLog(@"[dotsArray count] = %i",[dotsArray count]);
// Restore from NSValue to C structures
CGPoint pointRestored = [pointObj CGPointValue];
```

I want to be able to use:

```
[dotsArray insertObject:pointObj atIndex:0];
```

in place of

```
dotsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pointObj,nil];
```

so that I can increment the placing as I recall the method to store multiple points.

From reading I think this has something to do with the ID type required for the 'insertObject', but I don't fully understand it and am unable to find a solution online.

EDIT: When I use

```
[dotsArray insertObject:pointObj atIndex:0];
```

then

```
NSLog(@"array content: %@", dotsArray);
```

outputs NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addObject:` method.

```
[dotsArray addObject:pointObj];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Hi Prasad G, I had already tried this, when I used it i received , array content: (null) and dotsArray count] = 0, from the NSLog in the code. I also need to be able to add to the array at selected indices.

Comment: dotsArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init]; You should write in viewDidLoad method and declare dotsArray as global variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I needed a fresh set of eyes on that! I had it declared in the wrong place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The method which you want to use `[dotsArray insertObject:pointObj atIndex:0];` refers to the  id of the array that is the array position. This means `atIndex:0` is the first position in your array as the array starts from Zeroth position. So now if you put this in your **DotsArray** , the index which you want to call or the ID type is the value at the point you want to show.

Comment: I have edited the question to make my problem more clear. When I use said method, it NSLogs NULL. Any Ideas?